# how to pass exit results to a function

Tags: command-line, functions

I am trying to reduce the amount of code in a script. What I want to do is pass the result of a command to a function that tells me if the command passed or failed and then exits if it fails.

Here is the receiving function:

```
function SanityChk() {
    if [ $1 != "0"]; then
        echo "FAIL"
    else
        echo "PASS"
    fi
}
```

I know I could run the command and then just pass $? back...

```
sudo cp test.txt test.dat
SanityCheck $?
```

however I want to do it in just one line. I have been trying to use "eval" so it was something like this:

```
SanityCheck eval$(sudo cp test.txt test.dat)
```

but it seems to return anything BUT the result.

so the question is how can I get the exit result passed?

Comment: you are missing a space `[[ $1 -gt 0 ]]` double brackets are probably better to use. ( != is used for string comparison)

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass the command and all the arguments:

```bsh
SanityCheck () {
    if "$@"; then
        echo yes
    else
        echo no
    fi
}

SanityCheck sudo cp test.txt test.dat
```

Or, execute the function *immediately* after running the command: `$?` is the exit status of the **last command**

```bsh
SanityCheck () {
    if (($? == 0)); then
        echo yes
    else
        echo no
    fi
}

sudo cp test.txt test.dat
SanityCheck
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the exit status to a variable:

```
some_command
status=$?
```

Then you can do what you will with `$status`.